# Why does jQuery select only one element when chaining .attr() in selector?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, web-crawler

I have a simple list of links:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="1">link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="2">link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="3">link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="4">link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="5">link 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="6">link 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="7">link 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="8">link 8</a></li>
  <li><a href="9">link 9</a></li>
  <li><a href="10">link 10</a></li>
</ul>
```

How do I select these links with jQuery?

`$('a')` - this returns all the links

How do I get all the contents of these links ("link 1", "link 2", "link 3"...)?

`$('a').text()`

How do I get all the hrefs from the links (1, 2, 3...)?

<s>`$('a').attr('href')`</s>

NOT TRUE ^
IT SELECTS ONLY THE FIRST LINK and returns `1` instead of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`.

I know I could `map`, do `each` etc. but I'm writing a crawler that uses this a lot and wondered why is this happening and whether I can get all the hrefs without any loops here, just using jQuery's (preferably jQuery core) selectors?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/z5j1ty08/

Comment: So just to get this straight... you want to loop over the links (to get their contents) without any loops?

Comment: A loop is required, unless you want to hard-code each index, which is WET and silly. Don't do that. Don't be afraid of loops. Computers are *fast*.

Comment: You'll need loops. There's no other way. It won't affect the performance of your program.

Comment: I know it sounds stupid but somehow I'm getting ALL the links using `$('a').text()`, and loop is not needed. What's the deal here?

Comment: @Wordpressor

Description on `.text()` by jQuery: "Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the matched elements."

You can use `.text()` to get all the elements, but if you want to act over them individually, you need to loop through each element.

Comment: In contrast, [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) is used to "[g]et the value of an attribute for the *first element* in the set of matched elements."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really loop over DOM elements without, well, looping through them.

Looping won't have any dramatic effect on the performance of your web-crawler.

This being said, you're just looking at:

```
$('a').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/q1er5946/